# Altering a PDF document in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf

Is it possible to convert a PDF document to HTML or text and then edit some text of the html/text file and recreate the PDF, all in a PHP script?

Comment: Or this? :) http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  A website that alters a PDF in some way?  If you're also outputting a PDF I don't understand why you would want to convert it to HTML first.

Comment: because i try to edit some text in pdf file , but when i try to open it in php it gives some garbage value instead of text in it. Thats why i am trying to convert it in html/text first (for alteration) .

Comment: OK, so you're making something like an online PDF editor?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.pdflib.com/download/

Comment: Though I'm not sure that provides any way of opening an existing file

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen or attempted todo this.

I find it better/cheaper to do the following:

- Write the component that will do image intensive processing op a platform like .Net or Java. The application has be be console based and return/print the relevant info (if there was an error in processing etc).

  Call the command from you php web application.

  Php is a web language and used best for that purpose.